# Does the nerve of a category have a right adjoint?

Tags: ct.category-theory, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Taking the nerve of a groupoid gives a simplicial set. This is functorial $N:{\mathbf{Grpd}}\to {\mathbf{sSet}}$. NLab tells me that, in general, [nerve has a left adjoint](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve+and+realization), which is geometric realization. Does the nerve $N$ have a right adjoint?

Even better, does $N:{\mathbf{Cat}}\to{\mathbf{sSet}}$ have a right adjoint?

I realize I may be asking for too much, as here we are working internally to the topos ${\mathbf{Set}}$. Maybe it is better ask this question internal to an $(\infty,1)$-topos and ask only that the right adjoint exists up to homotopy. I would be interested in the respective answers for the $(\infty,1)$-topos ${\mathbf{sSet}}$ and ${\mathbf{Top}}$ instead of the topos ${\bf{Set}}$, which are basically the same up to homotopy.

Comment: In the groupoid case, the "geometric realization" of a simplicial set is its homotopy groupoid?

Comment: @Colin: It does not have a right adjoint, because as you will see with toy examples, it does not preserve colimits.

Comment: To complement Martin's comment, see Zhen Lin's answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/175966/does-the-nerve-functor-resp-fundamental-groupoid-functor-preserve-homotopy-co/175971#175971).